# Obtaining dictionary value in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is the dict:

```
sozluk_ata = {20225: 17, 20232: 9, 20233: 22, 20234: 3, 20235: 28, 20236: 69, ..}
```

And here is my code to get value of an element in dictionary.

```
ders_adi_entry_1 = entry_1.get()
ders_crn_entry_1 = int(entry_11.get())

y1 = "sozluk_%s[%d]" %(ders_adi_entry_1, ders_crn_entry_1)
print (y1)
```

This gives me `sozluk_ata[20225]`, not the value `17`.

Comment: Your code is not an MWE, see here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe

Comment: @Farseer ders_adi_entry_1 is ata and ders_crn_entry_1 is 20225 for example the user select it. There are multiple dics.

Comment: @MelihMuhammetGundogdu: Please provide some more code in order to show these multiple dicts and the user input.

Comment: @albert sozluk_tur={20374: 58, 20358: 31, 21825: 61..    sozluk_bil={25472: 65, 25473: 69, 20866: 40... like that, and in tkinter there are 2 entries. for example user writes ata to first entry and 20225 to second entry I want the program to give me 17.

Comment: Where do you get the data from? Do you generate those dicts by hand? I am just thinking about that since we need a datatype containing all the dicts to look at in order to search for the desired output value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the values of your dict, use somethink like:

```
sozluk_ata = {20225: 17, 20232: 9, 20233: 22, 20234: 3, 20235: 28, 20236: 69}

for key in sozluk_ata:
    print(key, sozluk_ata[key])
```

which prints:

```
20225 17
20232 9
20233 22
20234 3
20235 28
20236 69
```

Comment: there are multiple dictionaries. The user should select the dictionary thats why I had to use %s

Comment: If so, you might store these several dictionaries in another dictionary in order to 'search' for the correct dictionary by key.

Answer (score 2):

As a general approach I would suggest something like this:

```
def lookup(inp):
    inp = int(inp)
    for d in overall:
        for k,v in d.items():
            if k == inp:
                return v

overall = []

sozluk_ata  = {20225: 17, 20232: 9, 20233: 22, 20234: 3, 20235: 28, 20236: 69}
sozluk_tur  = {20374: 58, 20358: 31, 21825: 61}
sozluk_bil  = {25472: 65, 25473: 69, 20866: 40}

overall.append(sozluk_ata)
overall.append(sozluk_tur)
overall.append(sozluk_bil)

inp = input('Please type in a key: ')

print(lookup(inp))
```

This prints the corresponding value for a given key which the user typed in when asked. However, since it uses the list `overall` we are not able to tell in which dict the desired key-value-pair is contained. In order to provide this functionality you would need something like a dict instead of the list or a list of tuples.

Instead of appending the different dicts for each other (so calling `.append()` three times with different arguments) you could also `extend` the list with a list like:

```
overall.extend([sozluk_ata, sozluk_tur, sozluk_bil])
```

Answer (score 1):

We aimed to search 6-7 dictionaries and to get the value of the `crn_adı` variable which give us from users. (Also we want user to give us the dict that we search.)
We come through this problem like this:

```
sozluk_all = {"sozluk1": {keyandvalues}, "sozluk2": {keyandvalues}}
x = input()
crn_adı = input()

y1 = "sozluk_%s"%(x)
print(sozluk_all[y1][crn_adı])
```

thank you all